# Urdhva pundra on utsavar of Lord Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, sri-vaishnava, tilak

In Vishnu temples in South India, Urdhva pundra on utsavar of Lord Vishnu is like an inverted triangle whereas that on moolavar is the standard urdhva pundra i.e. two white vertical lines and red or yellow line in between.Why is different urdhva pundra applied on utsavar and moolavar?  [image]